# Exclude last column while exporting to excel

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

How to exclude the last column of datatable while exporting to excel format using jquery? I have tried `.not("#tableid")`, `.remove`, `exclude:"#tableid"` but doesn't work. Is there any solution for it???Below is my code

Table code:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped tableToExcel" id="tbl_datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Identifier</th>
      <th>Group Name</th>
      <th>Group Name English</th>
      <th>Fiscal Year</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>District</th>
      <th>District in English</th>
      <th>VDC</th>
      <th>VDC in English</th>
      <th>Ward No</th>
      <th>Program</th>
      <th>Livestock/Crop</th>
      <th id="noExl">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#exportExcel").click(function() {
        $(function() {
            $(".tableToExcel").remove("#noExl").table2excel({
                exclude: "#noExl",
                name: "Excel Document Name",
                filename: "Group",
                exclude_img: true,
                exclude_links: true,
                exclude_inputs: false
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: there are many with same id `noExl` its not allowed. Instead use a class name .

Comment: have tried class also but not solved

Comment: use a class name and call `$(".className").remove();` before exporting.

Comment: @artm that doesn't work either

Comment: If you look at the [**source**](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/blob/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js#L47), table2excel only allows exclude of entire rows `<tr>` not individual columns `<td>` so you must alter the source, i.e the `init()` function in order to accomplish what you want.  I dont think you can monkey patch it.

Comment: @davidkonrad will you please help me to figure out this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that can be done very quickly. Since we want to exclude entire columns I think using exclude classes as `.noExl` is a bad idea. Instead I introduce a new option, `columns` :

```js
defaults = {
   exclude: ".noExl",
   name: "Table2Excel",
   columns: []
};
```

Which specifies which columns that should be exported to Excel. The beauty is, that by doing so you can also specify the *order* of the columns. And then I changed the `init()` function loop to :

```js
$(e.element).each(function(i, o) {
    var tempRows = "";
    $(o).find("tr").not(e.settings.exclude).each(function(i, o) {
        if (e.settings.columns.length == 0) {
            tempRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
        } else {
            var row = "";
            e.settings.columns.forEach(function(colIndex) {
                //is it a thead or tbody row?
                if ($(o).find('th').length > 0) {
                    row += $(o).find('th:eq(' + colIndex + ')')[0].outerHTML;
                } else {
                    row += $(o).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')')[0].outerHTML;
                }
            })
            tempRows += '<tr>' + row + '</tr>';
        }
    });
    e.tableRows.push(tempRows);
});
```

It is here on github -> **https://github.com/davidkonrad/table2excel**

Some issues could be optimized, but at least it works. Now you can specify exactly what columns you want to export and in which order :

```js
//export only column #2 and #3 and in reverse order
//NB! columns[] is zero based
$(".table2excel").table2excel({
    name: "Excel Document Name",
    filename: "myFileName",
    exclude_img: true,
    exclude_links: true,
    exclude_inputs: true,
    columns : [2,1]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qyrbazur/**

In your case, if you want to exclude the last column, use

```js
$(".tableToExcel").remove("#noExl").table2excel({
    name: "Excel Document Name",
    filename: "Group",
    exclude_img: true,
    exclude_links: true,
    exclude_inputs: false
    columns : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
});
```